# jquery - how to shift player on scrolling

Tags: jquery

I read a news on the aol.com, I noticed something on the video player

[See this link](http://www.aol.com/article/news/2016/10/15/1-4-million-people-lose-obamacare-coverage/21582895/)

When I scroll, the video player shift to the right

I search on google but did not find anything about it and how can it makedid not find anything about it and how can it make

Comment: On scroll event change the video container position and it's width and height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/fobyaesd/3/):

```
$(window).scroll(function (){        
            var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

            var elemTop = $('#mydiv').offset().top;
            var elemBottom = elemTop + $('#mydiv').height();

            if(docViewTop >= elemBottom){
                //calculate new top for your div/player
                var newTop = (($(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop())-$('#mydiv').height());
                $('#mydiv').css({top: newTop, left: 200, position:'absolute'});
            }

        });
```

Comment: Yeah @Ehsan. You can tweak it to suit your requirement.